# mkvirtualenv: command not found after running source ~/.bash_profile

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm doing a setup for the tutorials on [newcoder.io](http://newcoder.io) . I'm setting up on xubuntu which is running in Oracle Vm on Windows 7. Everything goes off without a snag until I get to the part where I install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper.

```
 sudo pip install virtualenv
 sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
 export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
 echo 'export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs' >> ~/.bash_profile
 echo 'source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper' >> ~/.bash_profile
 mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
 source ~/.bash_profile
```

After I run

```
 source ~/.bash_profile
```

I get an error saying:

```
 mkvirtualenv: command not found
```

What can be done to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `virtualenvwrapper.sh` in your `.bash_profile` before the `/etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper` command. For example:

**.bash_profile**

```
...
source "/usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper
```

Comment: I tried that, and I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I installed virtualenvwrapper and all I had to do is log on again to my account. Any changes to .bashrc or .bash_profile were not required.